# RxSwift PublishSubject of type Optional<Any type> startWith nil

Tags: swift, frp, rx-swift

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
let reachedTopMostMessage = PublishSubject<Int?>()
reachedTopMostMessage.startWith(nil).subscribeNext { (_) in
    //
}
```

But the compiler complains with this error:

> 'Int?' (aka 'Optional') is not convertible to '(Int?...)' (aka
>   '(Optional...)')

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Optional<Int>()` to create a `nil` `Int?`, not just `nil`.

```
let reachedTopMostMessage = PublishSubject<Int?>()
reachedTopMostMessage.startWith(Optional<Int>()).subscribeNext { (_) in
    //
}
```